# NSTextField in NSTableCellView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstextfield

I have a view based NSTableView with a custom NSTableCellView. This custom NSTableCellView has several labels (NSTextField). The whole UI of the NSTableCellView is built in IB.

The NSTableCellView can be in a normal state and in a selected state. In the normal state all text labels should be black, in the selected state they should be white.

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to accomplish this would be to subclass NSTextField and to override the drawRect: method in your subclass. There you can determine whether the NSTableCellView instance containing your NSTextField instances is currently selected by using this code (which I use with a NSOutlineView, but it should also work with NSTableView):

```
BOOL selected = NO;
id tableView = [[[self superview] superview] superview];
if ([tableView isKindOfClass:[NSTableView class]]) {
    NSInteger row = [tableView selectedRow];
    if (row != -1) {
        id cellView = [tableView viewAtColumn:0 row:row makeIfNecessary:YES];
        if ([cellView isEqualTo:[self superview]]) selected = YES;
    }
}
```

Then draw the view like this:

```
if (selected) {
    // set your color here
    // draw [self stringValue] here in [self bounds]
} else {
    // call [super drawRect]
}
```

Comment: Seth's suggested method is the correct way and should be marked as the right answer. The method above is just wrong plus it's going to have an impact on scrolling / drawing performance

Comment: Unfortunately, Seth's solution only works on 'Source List' styled table views. In standard styled table views, only the blue selected state is NSBackgroundStyleDark. If an item is selected but the table view is not the first responder, you get a gray row highlight, and this is NSBackgroundStyleLight...

Answer (score 14):

Override setBackgroundStyle: on the NSTableCellView to know when the background changes which is what affects what text color you should use in your cell.

For instance:

```
- (void)setBackgroundStyle:(NSBackgroundStyle)style
{
    [super setBackgroundStyle:style];

    // If the cell's text color is black, this sets it to white
    [((NSCell *)self.descriptionField.cell) setBackgroundStyle:style];

    // Otherwise you need to change the color manually
    switch (style) {
        case NSBackgroundStyleLight:
            [self.descriptionField setTextColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.4 alpha:1.0]];
            break;

        case NSBackgroundStyleDark:
        default:
            [self.descriptionField setTextColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0]];
            break;
    }
}
```

In source list table views the cell view's background style is set to Light, as is its textField's backgroundStyle, however the textField also draws a shadow under its text and haven't yet found exactly what is controlling that / determining that should it happen.

Answer (score 0):

This works no matter what style the table view has:

```
- (void)setBackgroundStyle:(NSBackgroundStyle)backgroundStyle {
    [super setBackgroundStyle:backgroundStyle];
    NSTableView *tableView = self.enclosingScrollView.documentView;
    BOOL tableViewIsFirstResponder = [tableView isEqual:[self.window firstResponder]];
    NSColor *color = nil;
    if(backgroundStyle == NSBackgroundStyleLight) {
        color = tableViewIsFirstResponder ? [NSColor lightGrayColor] : [NSColor darkGrayColor];
    } else {
        color = [NSColor whiteColor];
    }
    myTextField.textColor = color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
 override var backgroundStyle: NSView.BackgroundStyle {
     get {
        return super.backgroundStyle
     }
     set {
        self.yourCustomLabel.textColor = NSColor(calibratedWhite: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)//black
     }
 }
```