# NSTableView with custom row background: prevent label to turn white on selection

Tags: cocoa, custom-controls, nstableview

I have a view-based `NSTableView` that uses custom `NSTableRowView` instances to draw custom cell backgrounds for normal and for selected rows.

My problem is that labels inside the table rows change to a white color when a row is selected. I assume the text field's cell realized that it is selected and inverted the text color.

However, this does not work well with my custom background/row selection. White text is not visible anymore. Is there a way to prevent the `NSTextField` from chaining its color with the selection (preferably without subclassing, because I have the same problem with an `NSButton`)?

Here's a screenshot with the selected row in the middle (white label is hard to see):

[image: selected row in the middle]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is to subclass `NSTableCellView` and override the `setBackgroundStyle:` method.

This is described in more detail in @Seth's answer to this question: [NSTextField in NSTableCellView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149138/nstextfield-in-nstablecellview) .

Comment: I have the same problem with an NSButton. It looks like this way I'd have to have a reference to each and every label in the view (there are 4 labels + one button). Is this really the way to go?

Comment: I don't get why this answer is accepted. `willDisplayCell` will not be called for view-based table views. I don't understand how this solves the problem.

Comment: @Monolo thank you very much! It did the trick and fixed my problem too.