# NSTableView group row text field selection

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I want to make a custom text selection in my table view.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9596390/1320374) awesome answer on how to set the colors, fonts, etc. of the cells.

However, there is one issue.

It does not work for group rows. I see that the method gets invoked, but I think the style gets overwritten somewhere in either the `NSTableCellView`, or in the `NSTableView` class.

How can I fix this?

---

### EDIT

It's a view based `NSTableView`

Comment: Try overriding `-viewWillDraw` in your cell view, call `super`, and then change whatever you want.